# How to add a placeholder for draggable items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

OK, so I've implemented a simple drag'n'drop test, using jQuery UI `droppable`, `draggable` and `sortable`.

Whenever an item from the left sidebar (e.g. input, password, etc) is dragged to the main part (the form editor), the element is "added" to the specified position.

When the existing items in the editor (after having been dropped) are dragged, they may easily be re-ordered, showing a dashed-border placeholder as for the exact position where the element is going to move. This one is done using `sortable`'s `placeholder`.

However, I still cannot figure out a way to get that working for items being dropped from the sidebar.

Any ideas?

---

The "draggable":

```
            $(".wrp").draggable({
                snap: false,
                stack: ".wrp",
                cursor: 'move',
                helper: myHelper
            });
```

---

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/xpayr4vt/

**Demo:** `http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html`

Comment: In your draggable event : `$(this).attr("placeholder", "Type your text here");`

Comment: @singe31 What exactly do you mean? In my `myHelper( event )` function?

Comment: I don't know, you don't give any code, I'm just guessing here.

Comment: @singe31 I have included the FULL page in question (http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html) and you can see the complete code.

Comment: @Dr. Kameleon You must provide a js fiddle so that we can add up a bit and help you out. Without that how we are supposed to help you. We can just guess your code.

Comment: @Yunus The complete code was included (http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html). However, I'll still try to create a fiddle out of it...

Comment: @singe31 Original post updated with the fiddle. Please, have a look! ;-)

Comment: @Yunus Just added the fiddle too! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was *too* simple. Omg...

All I had to do is connect the `draggable` to the `sortable`, like :

```
            $(".wrp").draggable({
                snap: false,
                stack: ".wrp",
                cursor: 'move',
                helper: myHelper,
                connectToSortable: "#theform",
            });
```

So much time wasted on such a simple thing. I hope this one helps anyone looking for the exact same thing... :-)

Comment: I don't see any relation with the title of your question (talking about placeholder). I doubt that someone will find an answer here because of the way you describe your problem, it's very unclear what was the problem.